# MVCPaging Css styles not working with Bootstrap 3.3.5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a problem getting the styles to cooperate. I downloaded the sample MVCPaging solution from his [site](http://mvcpaging.apphb.com/) and loaded the latest MVCPaging from nuget version 3.1.1. I copied the paging.css file from the sample solution and added it to my solution. You can see the problem in the image below. Both style sheets are being loaded as you can see from the debug window but yet their seems to be conflicts. Does anyone have a working css file compatible for bootstrap 3.3.5

I have the bootstrap.css bundled and loaded in the _Layout page and the paging.css has a link reference in the parent page for the partial that contains the pager

EDIT:
Removing the display:inline block css from the pagination element helps to get the pager inline but does not solve the problem. See second image.

but there are several other styles that are not working for this with bootstrap 3.3.5 including button and the coloring of the pager status section below the pager.

[image]

[image]

What it should look like, and remember I am using the same code from the sample. The only difference is the bootstrap.css version

[image]

One more update. In the sample solution I removed the reverence to the bootstrap.css bundle and set a link reference to the 3.3.5 cdn link and I got the same results as my project

[image]

Edit:

Here is a link to the files that are being used

1. [bootstrap.css](https://tresor.it/s#v1XYynUVRXne57D26m8xXQ) This is loaded in the _Layout.cshtml bundle
2. [paging.css](https://tresor.it/s#tnIRA8w5PKfDB0WQWA4Xqg) This is loaded in the partial view that contains the pager as a link reference

Comment: have you call this updated version bootstrap css file on your view page?

Comment: I'm using the 3.3.5 version of bootstrap. The same version I used on the sample through the cdn and it gives identical results.

Comment: can you share both file screen shot where you using bootstrap file. may be sequence is not correct.

Comment: @PankajGupta I updated the OP with the files that are being used.